# Don't show a Rtsp stream in an ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, video-streaming, gstreamer, exoplayer

I have two URLs. Both URLs started with "rtsp://", but the first URL is showing video and the second none.

The details my implementation

```
  ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .apply {
                addAnalyticsListener(EventLogger("RtspClient"))
            }

private fun createMediaSource(rstpUrl: String): MediaSource {
   return RtspMediaSource.Factory()
       .setForceUseRtpTcp(true)
       .setDebugLoggingEnabled(true)
       .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(rstpUrl))

}
```

In logs, I find only one distinguish

Log of not working a URL

```
tracks [eventTime=0.38, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0
group [
[X] Track:0, id=null, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.4d4028, res=1920x1080, supported=YES
]]
```

Log of working a URL

```
tracks [eventTime=0.56, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0
group [
[X] Track:0, id=null, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.4d4028, res=1920x1080, supported=YES
]
group [
[X] Track:0, id=null, mimeType=audio/g711-mlaw, channels=1, sample_rate=8000, supported=YES
 ]]
```

I think, it is not working because it's wait an audio road. But I don't know how I can disable this behavior.

Also, if I am wrong. In a stream that doesn't get video, I don't get in method's
onPlaybackStateChanged STATE_READY of state, only always STATE_BUFFERING of state

and both URLs get always repeat RTSP/1.0 200 OK, that mean that stream has been started